# Extended version of Mean-Value Theorem, lower bound result and reference request.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

The usual formulation of the mean value theorem in a real analysis course is something like this:

> **Mean Value Theorem.** Suppose $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open and convex set with compact closure $\overline{B}$. Suppose the map $f:\overline{B}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ the continuous in $\overline{B}$ and $C^1$ in  $B$. Then for all $x,y\in B$ there is $M>0$ such that
>   $$
> \|f(y)-f(x)\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{m}}}}
> <
> M\cdot\|y-x\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{n}}}}
> $$

But I wonder if there is any reference (article or book) that states and proves  the following version (something like ) of Mean-Value Theorem:

> Suppose $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open and convex set and a $C^{1}$ class map $f:B\to\mathbb{R}^m$. If there is $M>0$ and $m>0$ such that $m<\|Df(x)\|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^m)}<M$ for all $x\in B$, then 
>   $$
> \|y-x\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{n}}}}\cdot m 
> <
> \|f(y)-f(x)\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{m}}}}
> <
> M\cdot\|y-x\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{n}}}}
> $$

My main interest is the lower bound $\|y-x\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{n}}}}\cdot m $ for $ \|f(y)-f(x)\|_{_{\mathbb{R}^{_{m}}}} $.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't be, $(x,y) \mapsto e^x\cdot (\cos y, \sin y)$ is periodic in $y$ but its derivative is nonsingular.

Comment: @DanielFischer  This is a counter example ? If $f (x, y) = e^x (\cos y, \sin y)$ then there not exists $m> 0$ and $M> 0$ such that $m<\|Df(x)\|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)}<M$ because $\inf_{(x,y)}\|Df(x)\|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^m)}=0$ and $0<\|Df(x,y)\|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)}<e^x$.

Comment: If we take a bounded $B$, there are.